# Spring Ajax JQuery Jackson

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jackson

Whats wrong in my approach.

Java Mapping :

```
@POST
@Path("/receive")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void consumeJSONList(@RequestBody List<Question> clientList) {
    String output = "consumeJSONList Client : " + clientList.toString() + "\n\n";
    System.out.println(output);
}`
```

Ajax Call :

```
function addData(x) {

var x='[{"id":12,"email": "2","lang": "es"}]';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "rest/question/receive",
        header : {
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        },
        data: x,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('Wine created successfully');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(jqXHR);
            alert(jqXHR+'addWine error: ' + textStatus+"errorThrown"+errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

i am able hit the same url with same data in google post man but when use ajax call its throwing 415(Unsupported media type)

Please help to create a controller which can accept list of java object and process the same

Comment: `@Path("/receive")` << is this route was correct?

Answer (score 0):

As the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) say, you should give the following a try:

Replace…

```
header : {
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
},
```

…with…

```
dataType: 'json',
```

…and make sure that the server's context path in front of "/receive" is really "rest/question". Depending on the situation also a leading slash "/rest/question/receive" could be worth a try.